# What is pixel-wise product in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

What is meant by pixel-wise product between two images? opencv provides a function for this operation?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#multiply. Check the source

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-multiply) you can see how OpenCV does element-wise multiplication with cv::multiply.

They just multiply the elements and make sure that the result isn't larger than the maximum allowed value.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure which class you are talking about (being more specific would help), but in general element/pixel-wise product means, that you multiply each pixel of an image with the corresponding pixel of another image (both images need to be the same size). The result will be a new image, where each pixel is the product of the corresponding pixels of the two input images.

Another interpretation (not pixel-wise) is a matrix multiplication of two images. That's where the emphasis on pixel/element-wise stems from.

Comment: sorry I'll be more precise, here's what I do

at time t:

Ft = (|At - At-1|) pixelwise product (|At+1 - At|)

Comment: By more precise I mean a code snippet that illustrates what you are doing. That way we know which functions and classes you are using. However, from the description you have given so far, I am convinced that my explanation holds for your case.